# Strapi image (media) field doesn't show in the endpoints

Tags: strapi

Cannot see media field in my endpoint for my content type.

Data[title:"testing";
image:"myImage"]

{

"data": [

{

"id": 1,

"attributes": {

"title": "Testing",

"createdAt": "2021-12-03T16:04:09.535Z",

"updatedAt": "2021-12-03T16:20:36.636Z",

"publishedAt": "2021-12-03T16:04:10.329Z"

}

}

],

"meta": {

"pagination": {

"page": 1,

"pageSize": 25,

"pageCount": 1,

"total": 1

}

}

}